# Activate JavaScript formatting for [dojo] tag, similar to [jquery]

Tags: feature-request, tags, syntax-highlighting

**Dojo** is JavaScript framework, just like **jQuery**.

Tag [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) has automatic JavaScript syntax highlighting activated, so there's no need to manually specify the highlighting in case the question isn't tagged [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript).

The same should be done for tag [dojo](/questions/tagged/dojo). There are many questions with that tag, without [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) tag, and without propert syntax highlighting (which is extremally unintuitive to activate).